# Filter query column with time() Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have read a lot of posts in the forum but haven't been able to understand this error.

I need to count user's sessions ( login times?) with the timestamp less than 3 days.

My query.

```
Session::where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->whereRaw('`timestamp` < ' . time() -3 * 24 * 60 * 60)
                ->orWhereRaw('timestamp' . ' IS NULL')
                ->orderBy('date')->limit($usc - $user->devices)->delete();
```

Here is my mistake.

ReflectionException

```
Class App\UseCases\UserService does not exist
```

If I remove `` ->whereRaw('`timestamp` < ' . time() -3 * 24 * 60 * 60) `` from query, the mistake disappears.

I don't seem to find the error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: time() -3 * 24 * 60 * 60  code it like time() -(3 * 24 * 60 * 60)

Comment: I changed the query
->whereRaw('`timestamp <` ' . time() -(3 * 24 * 60 * 60))
But still, have the same error.

Comment: there is extra ` in the whereRaw after `<` sign

Comment: I have seen it, but in the code, I don't have it
->whereRaw('`timestamp` < ' . time() -(3 * 24 * 60 * 60))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `whereDate` filter provided by laravel:

```
Session::where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->whereDate('timestamp', '<', date('Y-m-d', time() -3 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                ->orWhereRaw('timestamp' . ' IS NULL')
                ->orderBy('date')->limit($usc - $user->devices)->delete();
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses